# Can I use RabbitMQ for email queuing in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, queue, apache-commons

I am working on Spring Boot. The scenario is the sending of emails which was achieved using Apache Commons, but the problem is that I can have one or more senders, given the case that there is more than one, it must be distributed
the number of emails to send between the senders with what is counted so that each sender is working and avoid an overload of emails as it happens in gmail, I thought that I could use RabbitMQ to achieve that, but I don't know if it is possible with this tool, any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: Normally your email server should already do this task. Are you talking about the message contains in the email or the email itself?

Comment: Thanks for answering. To the email itself

Comment: If it is the email itself I don't think you need to use Rabbit MQ. The mail server already manage every aspect from the reception to the delivery. You can instead manage the message with Rabbit MQ and wrap it into your email before sending them.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really new to this, it means that then Apache Commons already takes care of queuing these emails through the SMTP protocol, I don't understand when it says that I can manage the message with RabbitMQ and wrap it in the mail.

Comment: On the side of email containment it is that, but to divide the number of emails (let's say 8 emails) among the senders (2 senders) I could use RabbitMQ or it would be something else outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

if your system is big enough you can try **Kafka**. It's one of the alternatives **rabbitmq**